# jquery.datetimepicker set time only

Tags: javascript, jquerydatetimepicker

I used https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker.
I want to show and enter only time.
My code is:

```
$('#dttf').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    step:15,
    format: 'H:m'});
```

It is showed only time from 15 minutes, starting with exact time, e.g. 9:00,9:15,9:30, etc.
The problem is when I select time, 9:15 by example, it shows me 9:17, the current time.
I want to show what I selected, 9:15. I tried many options, but no one seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `H:i` as the format string instead of `H:m`.

```js
$("#date").datetimepicker({
  datepicker: false,
  step: 15,
  format: 'H:i'
});
```

```css
@import 'https://unpkg.com/jquery-datetimepicker@2.5.20/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-datetimepicker"></script>


<input type="text" id="date">
```

Comment: Sure. Could you accept the answer if it worked out for you?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
   $('#example').timepicker(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" id="example" />
```

Hope this helps you